# How to hide a tablix based on a specific value in a multiselect parameter

Tags: reporting-services

I need some assistance trying to hide a tablix.
The Scenario:
I have 2 tables on one report which has a multiselect parameter. I need to hide one table based on the selection. i need to show a specific table based on only one value now i have used the `instr()`and `Join()` functions which definitely work, but when i select all of the values i still get the table pertaining to the one specific value.
Example of code to show specific table;
`=IIF(Instr(Join(Parameters!Name.Value),"Name1")>0,False,True)`
This shows the table when 'Name1' is selected.... I want to show that table when ***ONLY*** 'Name1' is selected. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You should also check parameter count on your expression like below

```
=IIF(Instr(Join(Parameters!Name.Value),"Name1")>0 AND Parameters!Name.Count=1 ,False,True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come to the desired answer by just using the `join()` function and excluding the `instr()`. The code looks like the ffg:

```
=iif(join(Parameters!Name.Value(),",") = "Name1",true, false)
```

This works well.

Thanks for the help

---